# How can I decrease the value of an HTML element each second using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Here's what I have so far:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $(".auctiondiv .auctiondivleftcontainer .countdown").text(sec--);
}, 1000);
```

This works fine, but the problem arises because I have to set the value of `sec` on startup and every countdown element on my page has the same value. So instead of saving the value and decreasing that, maybe it's best to just get the value each tick and decrease it - without saving the value anywhere in Javascript.

How can I grab the text inside of the .countdown element (a `<p>` tag) and subract one from it and assign it back to the same `<p>` element? What has me confused is that there are many .countdown elements on my page, how would I go through each one?

I also need to make sure that a .countdown value once it reaches zero, I can do something. A conditional so to speak. I imagine I can use `.parent()` on it, but we'll see.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `each` method to iterate over the matched set of elements:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $(".countdown").each(function() {
        var newValue = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) - 1;
        $(this).text(newValue);
        if(newValue == 0) {
           //Do something
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

I've changed the selector to just `.countdown` because you said you have many such elements on the page, and I'm assuming they're not all going to be matched by your original selector, but you can obviously change that as necessary.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/RhXPC/8/) of the above code.

Comment: Thanks, this snippet will come very handy in learning about iterating through collections of matching elements. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the elements you use more than once in a variable to save resources.

Also, the used of `setTimeout` is encouraged over `setInterval` due to a difference in their behavior. You can read why [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts).

```
// cache elements to save resources
var $countdownElements = $( ".countdown" );

function countDown() {

    $countdownElements.each( function () {
        var $this = $( this ); // again, cache element for later use
        var newValue = parseInt( $this.text(), 10 ) - 1;
        $this.text( newValue );
        if ( newValue == 0 ) {
           //Do something
        }
    });

    // call this function again in 1 second
    setTimeout( countDown, 1000 );
}

countDown();
```